# Serverless Framework - Python and Requirements.txt - remove unnecessary packages

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am using serverless-python-requirements plugin for deployment of aws lambda; and I created requirements.txt using pip freeze > requirements.txt. However, requirements.txt may have more than needed packages (for deployment).

My question is: 
Can serverless-python-requirements plugin remove unnecessary package not used by my lambda function (keeping only that is directly or indirectly (dependencies) required)?

Comment: Short answer: `NO`. Long answer: `You need to manage your requirements by your self`

Comment: Why does it have more than you need for deployment? Use a virtualenv for development, and only install the packages you actually need.

Comment: @Chris Because it is in heavy development and every time I move/change import <somelib> I am hoping to not keep creating new virtual environment (also feels something doable by serverless/python in the 21st centuray - it seems not hard in the line of "pipreqs" but better).

Comment: What does heavy development have to do with anything? How does AWS Serverless have anything to do with how dependencies are defined and managed? You're not _developing_ on a serverless architecture, are you?

Comment: not AWS but I followed slimilar to [link](https://www.serverless.com/blog/flask-python-rest-api-serverless-lambda-dynamodb/) to convert/deploy my flask application as AWS Lambda. I am using this "serveless" software, if this makes my question and concern bit more clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Everything written here is applied for any project configuration (using virtualenv or not).

The correct strategy for this action is having more than 1 requirements file.

Let's say you have a default set  of libs that work for all environments.

you should put in a `common.txt` file.

Lets say you have two more configurations one for `dev` with debug libs, api documentation and navigation etc
and another for `tests` with testing frameworks coverage and that kind of stuff.

So in that use case you should have the:

`dev.txt`
`test.txt`

So now we have 3 files for 3 environments (prod, dev, test). The first line of `dev.txt` and `text.txt is should be:

```
-r common.txt
```

and now we can install only the requirement that matter for that environment.

There a good tutorial on how to do that in django (but it can be applied in any framework) in [this blog](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/02/django-best-practices-i-different.html)

Here is my final solution for a flask app we have:

**common.txt**

```
appdirs==1.4.3
CacheControl==0.12.6
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.3
contextlib2==0.6.0
distlib==0.3.0
distro==1.4.0
Flask==1.1.2
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
ipaddr==2.2.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
lockfile==0.12.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
msgpack==0.6.2
packaging==20.3
pep517==0.8.2
progress==1.5
pyparsing==2.4.6
python-dotenv==0.13.0
pytoml==0.1.21
requests==2.22.0
retrying==1.3.3
six==1.14.0
urllib3==1.25.8
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.15.5
```

**dev.txt**

```
-r common.txt
black==19.10b0
```

Also for install your packages, you should use the command:

```
pip install -r dev.txt #will install in order common.txt and dev.txt dependencies.
```

If I'm not clear, please let me know.